# Rxjs mouse events to achieve desired functionality in angular 6

Tags: css, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am developing angular app where UX designer came up with below interations.

In one section we have 2 sub sections like below image.
[image: Normal mode]

When I hover on Left section then that section will animate towards right like below image and some additional text shall appear

[image]

and when I hover to left section it will animate towards right like below image and some additional text shall appear:

[image]

I have achieved somewhat near to it and its CSS part.

1. **First Time app loads** then 50-50 section is visible
2. **when I mouseover Left section** its with should animate towards left (Vice versa for when I mouseover Right setion)
3. **When I mouse leave Left section and move cursor to right section** it should bring left section to normal and should animate right section (shown in pic 3)

However When I try to hover in and out quickly on left and right section it fires multiple events and end up with some undesirable behavior and simulated at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nuzopx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Fmain.component.ts).

Below is my Events in component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, Renderer2, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, debounceTime, map, merge, filter, combineLatest, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.scss']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('right') right: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('left') left: ElementRef;
  public showRightText = false;
  public showLeftText = false;
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    fromEvent(this.right.nativeElement, 'mouseover').pipe(
      debounceTime(1000)
    ).subscribe((e) => {
      console.log("event:Mouseover Right")
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.right.nativeElement, 'width', `150%`);
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.right.nativeElement, 'z-index', `4`);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.showRightText = true;
      }, 1100);
    });

    fromEvent(this.right.nativeElement, 'mouseleave').subscribe((e) => {
      console.log("event:mouse leave right")
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.right.nativeElement, 'width', `100%`);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.renderer.removeStyle(this.right.nativeElement, 'z-index');
        this.showRightText = false;
      }, 1100);
    });


    fromEvent(this.left.nativeElement, 'mouseover').pipe(
      debounceTime(1000)
    ).subscribe((e) => {
      console.log("event:Mouseover LEFT")
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.left.nativeElement, 'width', `150%`);
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.left.nativeElement, 'z-index', `4`);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.showLeftText = true;
      }, 1100);
    });

    fromEvent(this.left.nativeElement, 'mouseleave').subscribe((e) => {
      console.log("event:mouseleave LEFT")
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.left.nativeElement, 'width', `100%`);
      this.showLeftText = false;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.renderer.removeStyle(this.left.nativeElement, 'z-index');
      }, 1100);
    });
  }
}
```

I have replicated the scenario in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nuzopx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmain%2Fmain.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You are using RxJS as a mere replacement for 'window.addEventListener', but you COULD use it in a more powerful way. Consider using something like this:

```
const state$ = merge(
  fromEvent(this.left.nativeElement, "mouseover", () => "LEFT"),
  fromEvent(this.left.nativeElement, "mouseleave", () => "NEUTRAL"),
  fromEvent(this.right.nativeElement, "mouseover", () => "RIGHT"),
  fromEvent(this.right.nativeElement, "mouseleave", () => "NEUTRAL")
);

state$.subscribe((state) => {
  switch(state) {
    case "LEFT":    // yada yada
    case "RIGHT":   // yada yada
    case "NEUTRAL": // yada yada
  }
})
```

Now you have a stream of states.

You can then make it interactive in a next iteration:

```
const state$ = merge(
  fromEvent(this.left.nativeElement, "mouseover", () => "LEFT"),
  fromEvent(this.left.nativeElement, "mouseleave", () => "NEUTRAL"),
  fromEvent(this.right.nativeElement, "mouseover", () => "RIGHT"),
  fromEvent(this.right.nativeElement, "mouseleave", () => "NEUTRAL")
);

const interativeState$ = switchMap(state$, (state) => {
  return timer(1100).pipe(
    mapTo(true),
    startWith(false),
    map((isShowing) => ({ isShowing, state }))
  );
});

interativeState$.subscribe(({ state, isShowing }) => {
  switch(state) {
    case "LEFT":    // yada yada
    case "RIGHT":   // yada yada
    case "NEUTRAL": // yada yada
  }

  this.showLeftText = isShowing && state === "LEFT";
  this.showRightText = isShowing && state === "RIGHT";
});
```

The `switchMap` makes sure that your setTimeouts (as implemented via `timer(1100)`) are cancelled when the user interacts with the other side BEFORE the timer hits.

Golden rule in RxJS: you should only subscribe ONCE. In 9/10 cases that is the best way to structure your application.